# How do i check if a link has been visited?

Tags: css, firefox, google-chrome, hyperlink, userscripts

I am writing a userscript for myself and i have a list of permalinks and i'd like to hide the ones i already visited. I was thinking i can use jquery and check if the link has been visited (default color=purple) and if so hide the element.

However... i cant figure out how to actually check this. `.attr('style');` only gets me `border: none` while .css() is invalid.

How might i check if the link has been clicked on?
I am testing on firefox 4.0.1 with greasemonkey but i'll be using it on chrome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color checking shouldn't work anymore. Since this security flaw is fixed.

Comment: Thats a security flaw!?! even in a userscript? i know firefox lets certain things slide with userscripts

Comment: I think Johni means privacy issue. AFAIK, there was no security issues with this, it just exposes your personal information.

Answer (score 4):

a:visited is the selector you are looking for. This will return all visited links in the document.

```
a:visited {display: none;}
```

Comment: And `a:visited { display: none; }` or `:link:visited { display: none; }` will hide them.

Comment: How would i do that with jquery? cc @feeela

Comment: @Josh: Nice but I notice two problems. 1) Firefox doesnt seem to allow me to do this. 2nd) I need some type of rule to hide the block when the link has been visited rather then the link itself.

Comment: "How would i do that with jquery?" you get 1 lulz.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier to inject a `a:visited { display: none; }` rule?

Something like this in your Greasemonkey script:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

var style = document.createElement('style');

style.type = 'text/css';
style.innerHTML = 'a:visited { display: none }';

head.appendChild(style);
```

Comment: oh yeah d'uh that would be much easier. Ok so how do i inject it to the page? Do i write it in? i'd want `div.box a.item:visited {display: none; }`. How would i insert that with jquery

Comment: Cool. I notice two problems. 1) Firefox doesnt seem to allow me to do this. `style.innerHTML = 'a { display: none }';` works but :visited does not. 2nd) I need the block to hide rather then the link itself.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't allow you? What do you mean by hiding the "block"? Something outside the link itself? Can you update your question with more detail?

Comment: I think i may just inject code to call a function when i click a link and use local storage to check if a link has been clicked. I mean the div that holds the title, desc, etc of the link should disappear when i click the link. But i dont think i can do this anymore. css color in firefox gives me the same value if its clicked or not. When i say it wont allow me to do it i mean a:visited { display:none; } doesnt match any results thus hides nothing

Comment: The reason you can't test for the CSS color is that Firefox proactively blocks access to the computed style of links. Otherwise, a site can hide hundreds or thousands of links on their pages, test the computed style of them, and effectively have access to your browsing history. Not good.

Comment: I dont really see a harm in that but i understand why that may be blocked. I just have to do more work for my script which is a pity